# How to create a tansition effect between screens

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm using a `Conductor<Screen>.Collection.OneActive` with its `Items` bound to a `<ListBox>` in xaml. `ActiveItem` is bound to a `ContentControl` and it all works perfectly find out of the box to switch between screens. However, I want a transition effect (in this case a simple fade out and fade in) in between screen activations.

I've searched quite a bit on google but I couldn't really find anything without manually tying `ActivateItem` to say a button and have everything handle it from there. I want to keep using the simplicity of the `ListBox`.

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
<ListBox x:Name="Items">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding DisplayName, Converter={StaticResource UppercaseConvert}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do with the in box control, one way is to subclass and create your own Transition DependencyProperty/Collection, if you want more than one transition.  MahApps toolkit has one which the toolkit is free; as does Telerik for WPF.  Other solution, would be to go Windows Store App.  The Telerik solution has been pretty solid for WPF but controls are $$$.

I hope down the roadmap for WPF they refresh controls with some of the stuff they did in Windows Store flavor of the framework.